# Fuzzy (Like) Join not working

Tags: sql, join, fuzzy

I have the below code to match on similar characters where possible and it only brings through results from subquery A. Please can someone assist? Thanks

```
    select 
        * 
    from 
        (
            Select 'Test' T
        )a
        left join
        (
            Select 'Test1' T
        )b
    on
        '%' + a.t + '%' 
    like 
        '%' + b.t  + '%'
```

Comment: You can use wildcards only in the `like`  part

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `like` pattern only goes on the right side of the operator.  I think you intend:

```
on (a.t like '%' + b.t + '%') or
   (b.t like '%' + a.t + '%')
```